# необходим regex для получения массива строк из одной строки

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть строка типа "1. d3 c6 2. e3 a6 3. f4".
Не знаю как получить подобный массив строк:

```
[1. d3 c6] 
[2. e3 a6] 
[3. f4].
```

Необходимо чтобы строка в массиве начиналась с числа(0, 1, ..., 111) и точки. Потом может идти рандомное количество символов(два кейса, либо три символа ( h5), либо 6 символов( e3 a6)). При первом кейсе: пробел, символ начиная с a до h и цифра с 1 до 8. При втором кейсе: первый кейс повторяется дважды.

Будьте добры, подскажите пожалуйста способ. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Опишите подробнее формат строк в соответствии с описанием метки [tag:регулярные-выражения]

Comment: @dIm0n обновил описание.

Comment: У вас в примере строки 7 символов идёт " d3 c6 ", а не 6

Comment: `\d+\.(?: [a-h]\d){1,2}`   https://regex101.com/r/IUgt4X/1

Comment: @dIm0n Да, прошу прощения. Недоглядел. Последний пробел в самом конце присутствует всегда. Итого или 4 символа, или 7. Но есть третий кейс когда в самом конце этот пробел отсутствует

Comment: @alexsafsafsd добавьте это в описание

Comment: @splash58 ответьте в овтетах чтобы я проголосовал за верный ответ

Comment: @alexsafsafsd этот ответ найдёт 999, а вы сказали 0-111. И второе число 0-9, а не 1-8

Answer (score 0):

Вот так вот:

```
(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|10[0-9]|11[01])\.(?:\h[a-h][1-8]){1,2}\h?
```

Тест https://regex101.com/r/EpVsKC/1

> 1. d3 c6 2. e3 a6 3. f4111. f5112. f6101. q2

Находит:

`1. d3 c6`

`2. e3 a6`

`3. f4`

`111. f5`

`12. f6`

Comment: Та за шо минус?

Comment: Вы наверно здесь единственный человек, который себя здесь так необычно ведёт – собирает 1000 очков т.н. репутации и тут же её раздаёт, и так раз за разом. Обычно все тут гонятся за накоплением очков. Почему вы так делаете? Хотите таким способом научиться не привязываться к вещественным ценностям или почему? Держите + за ваше человеколюбие!